# Hibernate Statistics execution time meaning

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-statistics

What is the meaning of hibernate statistics result:

```
5535290951 nanoseconds spent executing 343 JDBC statements;
```

Is it Database only time, or is it Database time PLUS network time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plus network.

If you look at the Hibernate class [StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java) where this message is coming from, you'll see that this number corresponds  to variable name [jdbcExecuteStatementTime](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java#L277) that gets calculated [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java#L142) as the difference between the `System.nanoTime()`s ([beginning](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java#L134) and [end](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java#L142)).

So it includes the network latency since `System.nanoTime()` runs (twice) at the JVM.